# Android Studio statvfs

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I get the following log when I start the emulator :

```
17:27 Emulator: statvfs('/home/brunogustavo/.android/avd/test.avd/snapshots/default_boot/ram.img') failed: No such file or directory

17:27 Emulator: XIO: fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"

17:27 Emulator: after 60 requests (60 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

17:27 Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why does it happen? I'm using Debian 9.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Emulator 29.2.1 Canary (see https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2019/09/emulator-2921-canary.html)

Easiest way is to switch to the Canary Channel and install Android Studio 3.6 Canary 12.